# WordPress - using Ultimate Member plugin in your custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use Ultimate Member plugin in my custom theme which I created from scratch. Well actually I downloaded [this theme (freelancer)](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/freelancer/) from startbootstrap.com and used it as a basis. I activated the UM plugin and added the default pages, but I'm not able to view those pages in my custom theme. Do you need to add any pages or functions in order to activate the UM plugin in a custom theme?

The plugin does work on default themes like twentynineteen. So I believe I should be missing something in my custom theme.

Here is the directory structure of my theme:

```
wordpress
  wp-content
    plugins
      ultimate-member
    themes
      mytheme
        assets //copied from bootstrap theme
        author.php
        css
          style.css
        footer.php
        functions.php
        header.php
        index.php
        js //copied from bootstrap theme
        page-authors.php
        page-{category-posts).php
        single-post.php
        style.css
        ultimate-member
          login-to-view
          ...
          (and other files based on the article below)
```

I referred to this official article for template structure under /themes/mytheme/ultimate-member/ :
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1516-templates-map

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move forward when I added a singular.php file. I made additional changes on top of that but this file seemed to be the file I was missing.